# Is there a way to query Excel remotely to check if a macro is installed/enabled?

Tags: excel, vba

We use a custom macro to brand excel sheets, and I've been asked to confirm that this macro has been deployed to all end-user machines successfully. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the command prompt or PowerShell to gather this information, though on conducting initial research, it does not appear that is possible. I thought the macro itself might have an 'enabled' flag that I could use to figure this out, but that also didn't seem to be the case (though it's possible I overlooked it). I'm hoping that someone here will be familiar with requests like this, and might have a way to identify if this macro is both installed and enabled.

Thank you!

EDIT: This is a VBA macro that is manually enabled via File -> Options > Add-ins -> Manage: Excel Add-ins -> Check box for macro

Comment: "deployed" is not very descriptive - what exactly does "deployment" look like in this case?  How is it carried out?

Comment: @TimWilliams The macro is staged on the machine via GPO and enabled manually during deployment to a user. Management wants confirmation that this is available to all users.

Comment: If you have someone to set up the GPO they can't also check deployment was successful?  What kind of deployment/macro is it?  A VBA add-in?  A non-VBA add-in?  What does "enabled manually" actually involve?  Without details it's difficult to know what to suggest here.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the description with how this is enabled. On the GPO point, we're fairly confident that this has been deployed to the relevant machines, but management is looking for more direct proof that it's actually enabled instead of simply being installed/deployed. Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look at: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/registry-keys.htm

Comment: I have a similar thing at work. But the way I do it is to make the add in report it's version to a text file. So when I push out an update the add ins will ask the user if he/she wishes to update. If this person says yes then a record will be written in the text file with who updated, when and to what version. Another version of this would be to have an excelsheet it writes a "hearbeat" datetime in. This means you could detect if someone unticks the add in. I believe the method you ask for "you query the computers" is not possible since each computer needs to run this task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @TimWilliams, this link helped me greatly.
https://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/registry-keys.htm

Steps to identify if macro enabled remotely

1. Find SID of user

> wmic useraccount get name,sid | findstr "[USERNAME]"

2. Query registry

> reg query hku\[SID]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options /v
> "OPEN"

If key is found, macro is enabled. If not, macro is not enabled.